# Function not available for .Call using Rcpp.package.skeleton() and compileAttributes

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to follow closely the directions in the [Rcpp package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf), but I am getting the error

```
Error in .Call("MicroCreditLRVBR_TestJacobian", PACKAGE = "MicroCreditLRVBR") : 
  "MicroCreditLRVBR_TestJacobian" not available for .Call() for package "MicroCreditLRVBR"
```

The package framework was built with `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.  I copied in my `R` and `C++` code, modified the `Makevars` to point to some code outside the package,  updated the `DESCRIPTION` to link to `RcppEigen`, and ran `compileAttributes()`.  I then ran `R CMD build` to create a `.gz` file and `R CMD INSTALL` to install it.  It built and linked successfully, but terminated with the above error.

I can see that the function `MicroCreditLRVBR_TestJacobian` is indeed defined in `RcppExports.cpp` and `RcppExports.R`.  I don't know why it is not available for `.Call`.

Note that `NAMESPACE` includes `useDynLib(MicroCreditLRVBR)` and `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")`.

A public copy of the package in its current state is in [this github repo](https://github.com/rgiordan/MicroCreditLRVBR).  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is a typographical error that caused this issue in two places (as detailed below in my post).

Comment: The problem was not caused by a typographic error.  There was only a typographic error when I asked the question.  The actual solution is in my following comment.

Comment: The problem was a typographical error with: 1. package name in the `NAMESPACE` and 2. the inclusion of the demo script within the main contents as highlighted by my post. In addition, the example provided as-is was non-reproducible (and still is) to other user of *StackOverflow*. Both of which are valid criterion for asking for the question to be closed.

Answer (score 8):

When you switched the name from:

**MicroCreditLRVB**

to

**MicroCreditLRVB*R***

You forgot to modify the package name in the [`NAMESPACE` file](https://github.com/rgiordan/MicroCreditLRVBR/blob/5769d7f7cd17991b45612d23f6e105644079a126/NAMESPACE#L1)

e.g.

```
useDynLib(MicroCreditLRVB)
```

goes to:

```
useDynLib(MicroCreditLRVBR)
```

Also, remove lines 1-22 from [microcredit_stan_lib.R](https://github.com/rgiordan/MicroCreditLRVBR/blob/5769d7f7cd17991b45612d23f6e105644079a126/R/microcredit_stan_lib.R#L1-L22). They should be put into a "demo" file found within the `/inst`.

Lastly, import boost headers using the `BH` and cut down on the absolute paths within the `Makevars`.

Comment: With apologies, I copied this from a different private repo and forgot to change the NAMESPACE file.  That's not the problem, though.  The old package was called MicroCreditLRVB, and it still failed, and after changing the NAMESPACE here to MicroCreditLRVBR it still fails as described above.


Your other points are well taken, and I'd of course address them before making this package public.  For now, I've only created this repo for the purpose of asking this question, and I don't think they're what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by removing the line

```
jac_test <- TestJacobian()
```

from the file `microcredit_stan_lib.R`.

For future reference, I had a C++ file in `src/` that defined

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List TestJacobian() {
  ... do stuff ...
}
```

..and a library file `R/microcredit_stan_lib.R` that had a line in the outermost environment

```
jac_test <- TestJacobian()
```

By commenting out `jac_test <- TestJacobian()`, the problem was resolved.  I'm not sure why.